# How to concat multiple explicit image paths to video with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to figure out how to create a video from explicit paths to an image sequence.
I am writing these images from Houdini.

Instead of doing some kind of regex matching to replace $F3 with %03d I am trying to figure out how to concat the image paths into a video.

I'm trying to do something like this:

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 12 -i -start_number 1 -i test_00001.jpg -start_number 2 -i test_00002.jpg -start_number 3 -i test_00003.jpg -start_number 4 -i test_00004.jpg -start_number 5 -i test_00005.jpg -start_number 6 -i test_00006.jpg -start_number 7 -i test_00007.jpg -start_number 8 -i test_00008.jpg -start_number 9 -i test_00009.jpg -filter_complex "concat=n=3" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p $HOME/Desktop/test.mp4`

This result only plays a couple of frames in the result video

If I write the images to a text file with the following format
`file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_1.jpg'
file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_2.jpg'
file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_3.jpg'
file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_4.jpg'
file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_5.jpg'
file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_6.jpg'
file '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_7.jpg`

and then run a command like the following
`ffmpeg -y -framerate 12 -f concat -i /var/folders/fy/8zlxyq497kz0nzgb1nqc9xf59rwbjm/T/image_list.txt -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -c copy -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p $HOME/Desktop/test.mp4`

I get the following output
`[concat @ 0x7f870e809c00] Unsafe file name '/Volumes/hqueue/projects/Fire/render/test_1.jpg'
/var/folders/fy/8zlxyq497kz0nzgb1nqc9xf59rwbjm/T/image_list.txt: Operation not permitted`

Right now it's producing a video, but only with a couple of the input frames.

Comment: If your filenames are `test_00001.jpg`, `test_00002.jpg`..., then it's simply `-framerate 12 -i test_%05d.jpg` to read the whole sequence. If the filenames are `test_1.jpg`, `test_2.jpg`.. then change `test_%05d` to `test_%d`.

Answer (score 1):

I put selected files in one folder and use

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' output.mp4
```